# Get full tablename for custom sql query in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

In Orchard CMS, what is the best way to get the full table name? I want to perform a custom SQL query (so not using `IRepository<T>`), but would need the full table name for this. I know I can use `SchemaBuilder.TableDbName` but to create the SchemaBuilder, I also need an IDataMigrationInterpreter, featurePrefix and formatPrefix. Where do I get those? The IDataMigrationInterpreter I can get via the dependency injection mechanism of Orchard, but where can I get the prefixes, knowing I'm developing a module and so can't hard-code the prefixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tenant's table prefix (if any) is available in the injectable `ShellSettings` object. The table name that comes after that follows simple rules so you could hard-code that (since this is not dynamic, it only depends on the module's and the record's name).

See the built-in Upgrade module for examples, e.g. `Upgrade.Services.UpgradeService` and `Upgrade.Controllers.ContentPickerController`.

Example:

```
var tablePrefix = _shellSettings.DataTablePrefix;
var featurePrefix = "MyModule_MyFeature";
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tablePrefix)) {
    return $"{featurePrefix}_{type.Name}";
}

return $"{tablePrefix}_{featurePrefix}_{type.Name}";
```

Comment: It should probably be pointed out that it's generally not a great idea, that would result in brittle code. HQL is a much better choice, that will abstract those table name issues away, and will keep your code DB-neutral.